# A schoolbook question about an inequality equivalence.

Tags: logic

There is a line in my book:

for any $a,b \in \Bbb R$
$$a>b \implies a +c>b+c, c\in \Bbb R$$

I can't understand why it's an implication and not an equivalence $ \Leftrightarrow$

here is a picture of the passage:
[a pic from the book.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDoJB.jpg)
the problems start to appear from proposition (2)

Comment: The equivalence is true, which implies that the implication is also true, so where is the problem?

Comment: Well my book thinks that those two statments are NOT equivalent. That's why the book writes $\implies$ sign and not  $\Leftrightarrow$

Comment: Just because I wrote $\rm P\implies Q$ doesn't mean that I think  that $\rm P\iff Q$ is false.

Comment: Well, there the narrative of the chapter is not giving me options to think that the author would do this. Look at the pic. Some where he puts equivalent sings and in other places only implications.

Comment: If so, then case (0) (see the picture) should have an implication too, but it is not. Am I right? Or case (0) is much harder to prove? I'm not good at math at all, so there is a possibility that I just don't understand about what I'm talking here. Have mercy :)

Comment: Equivalence holds in statements (0), (2) and (4) in your extract from the book. If you need help with the text, then you'll need to provide a translation (as MSE is essentially a monoglot English forum).

Comment: You are right about the equivalence. The converse says that addition is right-cancelable for strict inequalities (as it is for equality). This is also true for the natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we accept the implication you quoted:

$$\text{for any }a, b \in \Bbb R\text{, }\quad  \forall c \in \Bbb R, \quad a > b \implies a + c > b + c \quad \qquad (\ast)$$

and try to prove the converse implication

$$\text{for any }a, b \in \Bbb R\text{, }\quad \forall c \in \Bbb R, \quad a + c > b + c \implies a > b.$$

Fix $a, b \in \Bbb R$ and suppose that for any $c \in \Bbb R$,
$$a + c > b + c.$$

Define $a' = a + c, b' = b + c$, then we can write this as
$$a' > b'.$$

By $(\ast)$, then

$$a' + c' > b' + c'$$

for any real number $c'$. In particular, you can take $c' = -c \in \Bbb R$ to get

$$\begin{eqnarray}
a' + c' & > & b' + c' \\
a + c - c & > & b + c - c \\
a & > & b 
\end{eqnarray}$$

---

So indeed, the converse implication is also true. Why the author did not write the converse is not clear, probably -- as mentioned by e.g. Workaholic in the comments -- not because they thought it was false but simply because they don't need the statement later on.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence holds, don't worry. The author probably needed only one direction. What is the context? Is it in a proof?

Comment: Added a picture in my post. Author speaks about how it is important to keep transormations of equation(inequalities) apart (implications and equivalent ones).